# Deploying text file to Panda II SD card

Tags: sd-card, microcontroller, .net-micro-framework

What is the best way to deploy text file to Panda II SD card? Text file has some configuration data that will be used by deployed application.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to take the SD card out of the Fez and plug it in to the PC, update your file, and put it back.

There are many ways, but you need a way to get the changes, whatever they are, out of your head and into the Fez.  When considering options, you need to know how often this would be done, whether there's a program change required as well and things like does this need to be done while "in the field".

My common method is to have a startup routine that writes out the configuration required to the SD card on startup every time I change my app (through a version stamp in the file and the app, so if they're different it goes and re-writes it).  If you have a network capability on the Fez (Wiz5100 ethernet) then you could program that capability over the network. So there are many ways, depending on how you want the entire system to work.